# can't connecting c# app to server,but PHP connects to it

Tags: c#, php, mysql, wpf

I've keep getting this message:"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." while trying to connect my WPF C# application to a remote database.
I've managed to connect from home using the same connectionString, but now I am in college and cannot seem to get it done.

I also have a website and i can connect to my database on the server using PHP.
My hosting server is FreeSqlDatabase.com if it helps.

What can be the reason for this problem ?
Is it have to do with IP address of my computer not getting access to the server ?
Can it be limitations of my college routers ?

**Update:**

This is my connectionString and it worked before:

```
connectionString="server=sql2.freesqldatabase.com;database=sql237801;uid=********;pwd=******‌​;Character Set=utf8";providerName="System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Comment: okay now now you need to show what you have tried

Comment: hard to tell without seeing code.

Comment: connectionString="server=sql2.freesqldatabase.com;database=sql237801;uid=********;pwd=******;Character Set=utf8" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient; This is my connectionString and it worked before.

Comment: There's no `;` between CharacterSet and ProviderName, is that correct?

Comment: There is a `;` on his question description, just not on this comment

Answer (score 0):

So the same C# application with the same connection string connects from your home, but not from college? This does not look like an issue with your code.

Most likely college routers are configured to block outgoing connections via less commonly used ports. See if you can reach the server from college using telnet in command prompt:

`telnet sql2.freesqldatabase.com 3306`

In case telnet is disabled on your machine, have a look at this:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/910.windows-7-enabling-telnet-client.aspx

Comment: it says Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed. Is there something I could do to work this around or i need to check this issue with my college ?

Comment: That means port is indeed blocked, because that command successfully connected on my machine. You can bypass this by using a VPN service that directs all your traffic via port 80. One service that offers free trial is http://www.ibvpn.com/ . I am sure if you spend some time looking for it, you can find free alternatives as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to connect with my Iphone and sometimes it worked and sometimes won't, but at least i know it's not a code problem.